# How to get all the users with Admincount=1 that are not in built-in privileged groups?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get all members that have the Admincount=1 attribute, and are not part of any of the built-in privileged groups. I'm just not sure how to do the part with the built-in privileged groups.

Here is what I've tried:

```
Connect-QADService -Service *****.org | Out-Null
$Domains="*****.org","*****.org","*****.org","*****.org","*****.org"
foreach ($Domain in $Domains)

$Users=get-qaduser -sizelimit 0 -searchroot $Domain/ -LDAPFilter “(admincount=1)” | where-object {($_.AccountIsDisabled -eq $False) -and ($_.AllMemberOf -ne "*,CN=Builtin,*")}
```

Comment: If everything but the 'builtin' check is not working try `(-not $_.AllMemberOf -imatch "CN=Builtin")` or this one `(-not $_.AllMemberOf -ilike "*,CN=Builtin,*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have the Quest cmdlets but should be easy to assume that `AllMemberOf` is an array. Couple points about using `-eq` or `-ne` in this case is that they dont use wildcards and you are comparing a string to an array. Point being that this is not the way you would make that comparison. Using the `ActiveDirectory` cmdlets, if that is an option for you, you could do this.

```
Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter "(admincount=1)" -Properties memberof | Where-Object{(($_.Memberof -join "") -notmatch "cn=builtin") -and $_.Enabled}
```

Since it looks like you are excluding users if they are in a builtin group we just join all the groups into one big string and test for a match.

Also I would heed Mjolinor advice. Never steered me wrong yet.

I noticed that `AllMemberOf` is supposed to be good for getting membership from other domains since `Memberof` does not have this information. I can't test this but updating your code would give you something like this:

```
$Users = Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 -searchroot $Domain/ -LDAPFilter “(admincount=1)” | 
    where-object {(!($_.AccountIsDisabled) -and (($_.AllMemberOf -join "") -notmatch "CN=Builtin")}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for what I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just change them all to 0, within an hour the AdminSDHolder process will change all of them that are a member of a protected group back to 1.

[AdminSDHolder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.sdadminholder.aspx)

Comment: Thought about doing this, but needed the other for reporting.

Comment: Just search for the user with AdminCount set to 1, and save that list.  Set them all to 0, wait an hour, run the search again and compare the lists.  Whatever was on the first that isn't on the second had the admin count set but wasn't a member of a protected group.